# Read a line from a text and enter as input until EOF

Tags: c, arrays, fromfile

I have written a program that when executed, prompts the user to enter an integer for five times. It returns two arrays,one containing the odd numbers and the other one, the odd ones.

---

**This is my code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 5

int array[SIZE];
int odd[SIZE];
int even[SIZE];
int index_odd=0;
int index_even=0;

int main()

{
  for(int i=0; i < SIZE; i++)
  {
    scanf("%d", &array[i]);

    if(array[i]%2==0) 
    {  
      odd[index_odd]=array[i];  
      index_odd++;  
    }   
    else  
    { 
      even[index_even]=array[i]; 
      index_even++;  
    }
  }

  printf("\nOdd numbers: \n");
  for(int i=0; i < SIZE; i++)
    printf("%d ", odd[i]);
  printf("\nEven numbers: \n");
  for(int i=0; i < SIZE; i++)
    printf("%d ", even[i]);
  printf("\n");


  return 0;
}
```

Is it possible for the program to, instead of reading from a terminal, to read from a text file, as in a **turn-by-turn based game**:

- read a line as input
- assign input(value) to the right array
- read the next line
- assign input(value) to the right array

and so on until `EOF`.

The actual thing I am trying to build is a **CARDIAC COMPUTER** simulator, and the way it works is, it takes a series of numbers, assigns them to the right indexes of an array and then depending on what values they hold, performs operations within that array and outputs the result.

**What do I need to implement in my code in order to:**

- read line from a text file
- save it to the assigned index/array
- read next line
- save it to the assigned index/array

Comment: Your print loop for odd numbers should be: `for(int i=0; i < index_odd; i++)` and your print loop for even numbers should be: `for(int i=0; i < index_even; i++)`. When you loop to `SIZE` you're outputting too many numbers (i.e. half are even and half are odd) and the later numbers will print random/garbage.

Comment: Open the file and call `fscanf()` until it returns `EOF`.